# Laravel: Able to Use 1 Query With Optional Pagination?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm constantly running into issues where I would like for my data to be paginated, but I also would like a general count of all of the data, or need to reference it for other purposes. Here is a sample:

**Controller**

```
$issues = Script::where('status', 'Other')->orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach ($issues as $issue)
  {{$issue->name}}
@endforeach
{{$issues->links}}
<br>
Total Issues: {{$issues->count()}}
```

The `foreach` issues display works well, but the `count()` for total issues just displays the paginated length as a result. I understand why it does this, so as a workaround, I have been adding a second query to the Controller:

```
$issues_raw = Script::where('status', 'Other')->orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc');
```

And then for any total count or other instances where I need unpaginated access to the data, I use `$issues_raw`. My question is: Is there any way to get around this by using just 1 query rather than the 2 I currently use? This feels inefficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `{{ $issues->total() }}`?

`$results->count()` gets the number of items for the current page.

`$results->total()` Determine the total number of matching items in the data store. (Not available when using  simplePaginate).

You can check all the possible functions here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#paginator-instance-methods

Answer (score 1):

in Laravel 5 you can use `total()`: `{{ $issues->total() }}`, will give you total records

Check [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination#usage)